# How to remove $_POST in php

Tags: php, post

I am writing a PHP page, which is about Good player voting. I am using $post method. So when somebody cast a vote

```
 if(isset($_POST['amla'])){
            $amla = "update players set amla=amla+1";
            $run_amla =mysqli_query($conn , $amla);
            $_POST = array();
            echo "<script>alert('Your Vote is successfully casted');       </script>";
        }
```

So when I use the print_r statement after this to check value of $_post the ooutput is :  array();

But when i refresh the page $_post variable appear with its previous value rather than empty array which causes a logical error a cast a vote automatically. how can i clear the $_POST so that even it is still clear after the page is refreshed.

Comment: What's your _actual_ question? Simply "Removing `$_POST`" doesn't make sense.

Comment: guessing you wont to know how to remove a var from the post array. 
$_POST['amla'] ='';      $_POST is a predefined array. You can't destroy it, but you can populate it with lots of nothing.

Comment: Right, so it's refreshes you have a problem with. The general solution is, after doing any processing necessary, redirect the user to another (or the same) URL as it's the browser that re-sends the POST data, not PHP storing it.

Comment: When you refresh the page it resubmits the POST data.

Comment: `"when i refresh the page $_post variable appear with its previous value"` - No, it appears with the value you're providing when you tell your browser to send the value a second time.

Comment: IS there any way to remove that $_post??

Comment: ... did you read any of the comments? Redirect after you're done with the data.

Comment: yes i got that... but i trying to understand $_POST method as i am new in web.

Comment: `$_POST` is a superglobal. It is populated before your script runs with the data that is sent to PHP (in your case, from a user's browser) in a certain way (form-data). As soon as the request is finished and returned to the client, the data is no longer available.

Comment: For more information, please see [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: thankyou for the help.

Comment: are you using `AJAX` to send the `POST` or `submit`ing a `form` ?

Comment: Don't assigne value to $_POST like you did.
Create a new variable, put it in session, or whatever but the POST is not for what you try to do

Comment: The `refresh` key is the bane of the html form programmer.  People hitting `back` or `refresh` causes many headaches. You will have to include a lot more code and send some kind of 'serial number' to test and prevent such a refresh from occuring.

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
$_POST = array();
```

with

```
unset($_POST);
```

Now the post statement should be empty.